# Math problems with Object data in DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe

At first, I tried to read some CSV file by Pandas. However, I encountered the error:

> DtypeWarning: Columns (6) have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.

Then I try this: `data=pd.read_csv('ALL.csv',dtype=object)` which works wonderfully.

My further code:

```
data=pd.read_csv('ALL.csv',dtype=Object)
data['party'] = data.cand_nm.map(parties)
sort_by_occupation=data.pivot_table('contb_receipt_amt',index='contbr_occupation',columns='party',aggfunc='sum')
```

!! the #parties is actually a dict where `data.cand_nm.unique_values` is the keys and values should be `Democrat or Republican`

but
[I tried to do the math it wont work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FM2I.png)

because the type of value is Object not integer:

This is my trial

```
z.Democrat[:5].values.astype(str).astype(int)
```

I have the error:

> OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long

Someone told me about int64 bit but personally, still not very clear about that. Would appreciate any helps along with some explanations.

For your information of dataset: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/benrolfs/pydata/master/ch09/P00000001-ALL.csv

Comment: Hi, please paste an example of your csv file into your question, along with an [mcve]. This may help answerers understand the problem clearer. (Additionally, please refrain from posting images of code.)

Comment: Is this a public data set (the CSV in question)? I'd like to poke around at it.

Comment: @coltoneakins It is a public dataset. Sorry for your inconvenience. I already add the link it at the end.